# What is the correct form of "advance" in the sentence: "My advance search"?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, participles

Which form is correct?

```
My advance search.

My advanced search.
```

I ask this in comparison to "simple" that does not have a 'ed' form.

```
My simple search.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Advance search" suggests a search that you did before some event, e.g. "my advance search led me to this particular car dealer".  "Advanced search" means that the search operation was in some way advanced, which sounds like the case you're describing.

However, I'm not used to seeing "advanced" (or "simple") used in this way.  If I'm talking about an operation I just performed on Google, I'm far more likely to just say "my search".  What nuance are you trying to capture?

Comment: In this context, advanced often allows for extra criterion or limits to be specified. For instance: "Foo" vs "title:foo author:Baz Bizizzle" (where the first instance might search against all possible data fields) or even allow for operations such as `select foo from bar where author in (select authorid from authorstable where lastname like 'S%'"` which would select authors starting with 's' and then cross-reference that list against a second dataset

Answer (score 2):

*My advanced search* is correct.

"Advance" is a verb, suggesting that you are advancing or moving forward, while "advanced" is an adjective describing that your search is more complex. "Simple" is also an adjective indicating that your search is not complex.

Comment: Good answer too, but Monica Cellio answer's was more complete.