# Is "advance bookings only" correct?

Tags: phrases, differences, adjectives

On a sign for a taxi company, which of the followings is correct:

> **Advance** bookings only

or

> **Advanced** bookings only

and why?

Comment: Related but not (I think) a duplicate: [What is the correct form of "advance" in the sentence "My advance search?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27990/what-is-the-correct-form-of-advance-in-the-sentence-my-advance-search)

Comment: *Advance* is correct, since the point is that this taxi service is limited to those who *book* (reserve, bespeak) their rides in *advance* of (before)  actually taking them. *Advanced* bookings would mean bookings that require a highly developed knowledge of how to book a ride, and a taxi service naturally wants to keep the process simple enough so that there is no occasion for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct form is *advance booking*, with *[advance](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/advance_3)* used as an adjective.